# Hikari cannot create a pool connections

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I need to implement the JDBC Pool Connection with the Hikari library, but I can't get it to work. My code is the followings:

```
public class DataSource {

    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;
    static {
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Test;integratedSecurity=true;");
        config.setUsername("****");
        config.setPassword("*********");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
        ds.setMinimumIdle(5);
    }
    private DataSource() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        HikariPool hikariPool = new HikariPool(config);
        System.out.println("POOL Active Connections -- " + hikariPool.getActiveConnections() + " Total " + hikariPool.getTotalConnections());
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

```
public class MainSample {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainSample.class);

    public static void loadDriver(String driverClassName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(driverClassName);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("POOL " + threadName);
            try {
                fechData();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor1.submit(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("POOL " + threadName);
            try {
                fechData();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor2.submit(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("POOL " + threadName);
            try {
                fechData();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

When I ask for the number of active connections. It always responds with 1 active connection.

Could you please give me, some ideas on how can solve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible there is only 1 active connection and 5 idle connections? You only make one request and it would make sense to reuse that one connection rather than others, especially in a single threaded environment.

Comment: You're creating a new config on every call, refer to the static config.

Comment: I tried to reproduce many connections in Hikari but I can't it. Do you have any example where can I see how Hikari can generate many active connections?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? Are you referencing the static variable HikariConfig and not the local HikariConfig you're re-creating on each call?

Comment: HikariPool* You need to create the HikariPool once.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help.  Yes, I reviewed your comments and I changed the code taking into account your feedback. But I received the same behavior.